# How do I solve $980 = 98t + 1080e^ \frac{-t}{10}$ for t?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This came up in a differential equation, and I wondered if there is an algebraic way to solve this for $t$ without using WolframAlpha.  Or is it a case of estimating with a power series?

Comment: I'm afraid it will have to be the second option: power series.

Comment: Some algebraic manipulation (let $z = 98t-980$) and the Lambert W function might do it.

Comment: @martycohen looks like I'll have to introduce myself to the Lambert W function.

Comment: Specifically, $t = 10 + 10 W(-54/(49 e))$ where $W$ is any of the branches of the Lambert $W$ function.  However, none of the solutions is real.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical analysis will make short work of this, but don't expect an algebraic solution.  Polynomials and exponentials don't play nice together.  Any one dimensional root finder should handle it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Set $t=10z$. Then you have to solve:
$$\frac{49}{54}(1-z)=e^{-z},$$
that has no real solutions in virtue of the convexity of the RHS.

In fact, for any positive real number $r$,
$$\forall z\in\mathbb{R},\quad e^{-z}\geq \frac{1}{r}(\log(r)+1-z)$$
holds, so, if we choose $r=\frac{54}{49}$, we have:
$$e^{-z}\geq\frac{49}{54}\left(\log(54/49)+1-z\right)>\frac{49}{54}(1-z).$$